# output error in libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svm, libsvm

Using Libsvm on ubuntu plateform, following is what i observed:

```
shuf negativeSet.scaled |head -2000 > negativeSet.scaled.2000
cp positiveSet.scaled trainingSet
cat negativeSet.scaled.2000 >> trainingSet 
cp positiveSet.weights trainingSet.weights
head -2000 negativeSet.weights >> trainingSet.weights 
./svm-train -s 0 -t 2 -h 0 -W trainingSet.weights trainingSet
```

output

```
optimization finished, #iter = 2525
obj = -3548.316727, rho = 1.515229
nSV = 2191, nBSV = 2152
Total nSV = 2191
```

commands used:

```
cp positiveSet.scaled trainingSet
cat negativeSet.scaled >> trainingSet 
cp positiveSet.weights trainingSet.weights
cat negativeSet.weights >> trainingSet.weights 
#training the data set to create a model
./svm-train -s 0 -t 2 -W trainingSet.weights trainingSet
```

output

```
optimization finished, #iter = 1
obj = nan, rho = nan
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 0
```

Please help me explain this discrepancy in the performance of svm.

Comment: Please note that you are using the default values for C and gamma and they are very unlikely to work out of box. In the first case the  shrinking heuristics are helping you but I am not surprised that the underlying optimization problem is not feasible with the default parameters.

Comment: how do i figure out which gamma and C parameters to use, except hit and trial? additionally is there a tool or way to optimize performance of libsvm? Thanks

Comment: You could use cross-validation and grid search, although if you are new I would recommend you to do some more manual experimentation so you know how change your model on each parameter. BTW, this guide is a good start : http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to try various C and gamma value on your training kernel. Besides, it seems like your negative samples are too large, so randomly picking up a subset from them is a better strategy like what you did in your approach 1.